# How _ to_ set_ `list.len=1000`_ globally_ in_ R?

Tags: r

I want to avoid `[list output truncated]` when `str()`,then I tried but failed:

```
options(max.print=100000,str = strOptions(list.len=1000))  
options(max.print=100000,list.len=1000)
```

How  to set `list.len=1000` globally in R?

Comment: Are you aware that printing large lists without truncation can take an immense amount of time?

Comment: As far as I can see, no option is passed to `list.len`. You could write your own wrapper function that calls `str` and passes a larger number to `list.len`.

Comment: `no option is passed to list.len`?,Sad!

Comment: or just use `str(df, list.len = ncol(df))` for `df` with any columns.

Answer (score 0):

This works with a data frame:

```
op <- strOptions(list.len = 1000)
str(myDataFrame, list.len = op$list.len)
```